# Does a subalgebra of a Lie algebra $g$ define a Lie subalgebra in the dual $g^*$ if $( g, g^*)$ is a Lie bialgebra?

Tags: lie-algebras, poisson-geometry

**Question:** Let $\mathfrak d = \mathfrak g\bowtie \mathfrak g^*$ be the double of the Lie bialgebra $(\mathfrak g, \mathfrak g^*)$, and let $\mathfrak h$ be a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak g$. If $\xi,\eta\in\mathfrak g^*$ such that

$$ \xi(x)=\eta(x)=0, \quad \forall x\in \mathfrak h $$

then is it possible to prove that $([\xi,\eta]_{\mathfrak g^*})(x)=0,\,\forall x\in\mathfrak h$ as well?

This seems to be an important part in proving Theorem 1.1 in V.G. Drinfeld's article "On Poisson homogeneous spaces of Poisson-Lie groups", but I'm having trouble reproducing it. The article itself says *"The proof of Theorem 1 is simple and more or less straightforward"*, so does anyone agree with the author?

Article link: http://www.mathnet.ru/links/e57aaacb0b7a60933c6976d46cd746c2/tmf1461.pdf

Comment: I was wrong about this being part in proving the theorem, as I reproduced the proof and did not need this at all. The proof also does not allude that it is at all possible to prove such a statement, so there probably exists a counterexample out there ;)

Answer (score 1):

It does not. A Lie subalgebra $\mathfrak h\subseteq \mathfrak g$ such that its annhilator $\mathfrak h^\bot$ is a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak g^*$ is called a coisotropic subalgebra.

An equivalent condition is that $\delta(\mathfrak h)\subseteq \mathfrak h\wedge\mathfrak g$. Checking this condition it is easy to find non coisotropic Lie subalgebras inside a fixed Lie bialgebra.